# How do I clone a Wordpress site to another domain both on same server?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, server

I have a wordpress site up and runnign and I want to copy the exact content to another domain. Both domains and servers are the same. I tried using some plugins like https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ but I kept getting 500- server error...

I don't know of another way that I can clone the site. I use Hostgator and have the Croc package... Both of my sites will serve as my portfolios but I will add more stuff unto one of them only...

Any help is welcomed
Thanks

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User (Stack Exchange)

Answer (score 2):

I use [a plugin called WP Clone](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/) which has worked fine for me to clone an entire site